# DateTime does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace GenericSomething
{
    public class Specific : Generic
    {
        public override bool DoSomething(string date)
        {
            DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            if (newDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        } 
    }
}
```

When I'm debugging and i use "Add watch" on DateTime.Now.Date, i get

> "DateTime does not exist in the current context."

And the condition is never satisfied even if the dates are the same.

Why is that is I'm including System?

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this? In the watch window? Evaluation window? Is it *just* in debugging? Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: debugging or building?

Comment: also please note, that you are comparing DateTime.Now.Day int value with DateTime value

Comment: `newDate` is a `DateTime` and `DateTime.Now.Day` is an `int`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i wrote the if clause wrong sorry xD

Comment: @HélderGonçalves `newDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Day` doesn't work neither. Still comparing `DateTime` with an `int`.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt debugging in watch window.. it never enters the if even if the value is the same

Comment: @SonerGönül again was wrong xD

Comment: Are you sure you were debugging the above code? The code won't even compile since there's no `;` after `return true` and `return false`.

Comment: i just passed the code from another computer... i forgot some syntax while passing.. but the code is the same

Answer (score 6):

Here a few things I saw;

- You might be need to add *mscorlib.dll* as a reference in your project.
- You can't compare with `DateTime` (*newDate*) and `int` (*DateTime.Now.Day*) with [`==`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) operator. You might need to use `newDate == DateTime.Now` instead.
- You are missing semi-colon (`;`) after your `return` statements.
- You need to add [`System.Globalization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.aspx) namespace for using [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) class.

Comment: I updated my question... there was some "mistypes". I was in a hurry xD

Answer (score 1):

Also, check to make sure that you have typed in "DateTime" and not "Datetime" or something else.  It has to be "DateTime" (camel case).