# The name DateTime does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am creating code to read from a CSV file. I am trying to output certain elements of each line from the file, but I keep getting the error "DateTime does not exist in the current context". The code appears to be fine in VisualStudio but when I take it back to Unity it reports the error.

```
void ParseData(string data)
{
    //09-Mar-20,10-Mar-20,7,4,7,4,7,4

    List<string> lines = data.Split('\n').ToList();
    lines.RemoveAt(0);
    lines.RemoveAt(lines.Count - 1);

    List<TimeData> dataList = new List<TimeData>();

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        List<string> lineData = line.Split(',').ToList();
        TimeData timeData = new TimeData
        {
            date = DateTime.Parse(lineData[0]),
            var1 = int.Parse(lineData[7]),
            var2 = int.Parse(lineData[3]),
            var3 = int.Parse(lineData[4]),
        };
        dataList.Add(timeData);
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

An example of the format of one of the dates is "09-Mar-20". I have tried to use DateTime.ParseExact(lineData[0],"dd-MMM-yy");
however that just returns the same error.

Comment: using System; is needed

Comment: are you missing `using System;` at the top of the code file? note: most IDEs will happily add that for you automatically, as a suggestion against the error - for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Khy.png (press ctrl+. or just click on the lightbulb)

Comment: `ctrl + .` on VS will helps you to add missing libraries in your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526584/datetime-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: I forgot to add that I have using System; The code itself has no errors in VisualStudio so theres no lightbulb or anything I can press for help.